# Compute shader in directx 12?

Tags: directx

I was just wondering since directx 12 is out does it have a compute shader like directx 11??? Ive tried searching and didn't find anything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about enumerating the features of a particular piece of technology.

Comment: how is DX functionality not about game development? jeez Josh ... chill out with this overkill moderation

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does and they work the same way as in DX11

Comment: DirectX 12 and DirectX 11 have essentially the same feature set. The difference is in how that features are exposed. If you are new to DirectX, then you should probably stick with DirectX 11 until have mastered it. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719853/directx-c-3d-engine-programming-learn-now-or-wait-for-directx-12) for more information.